# Replacing thermostat on Sanyo mini split

Tags: hvac, thermostat, mini-split

I have an old Sanyo KMH 0922 mini split.  The air conditioning seems to work OK.   Last winter on heat it  was either on or off the thermostat wouldn't control the temperature correctly.

This winter initially the thermostat seemed to work correctly for a few weeks. It would cycle the unit on and off at what seemed to be the correct temperature. Now the unit isn't coming on and the standby light on the thermostat is staying on.

I think that the thermostat is bad and I'm wondering if I could replace it with just a standard thermostat. Could I take the wires out of the old thermostat and plug them into a new normal thermostat? Are the wiring color codes the same?  I've replaced a few thermostats for furnaces and HVAC units.

I have a second mini split that shares the same outdoor unit.   It works fine.

This unit is quite old and Sanyo is gone from this market (bought by Panasonic) so new thermostats are no.longer available.

Comment: can you force the unit to come on heat when plugged in? if so, you can switch the power on and off based on temp, using smart outlets, an appliance timer, a regular thermostat+relay, etc. i did this to a cheap space heater w/o thermostat, works well.

Answer (score 2):

### Mini-splits, sadly, do their own thing

Most mini-splits do *not* use a standard thermostat -- instead, they use a remote-control module that communicates with the processor on the control board.  This allows for advanced modulating control, but has the downside that once either the remote or the control board starts to fail, you're SOL if spare parts are no longer available for your model.